# MySQL select query comma separated numbers filter result

Tags: php, mysql

My table look like this:

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgGL2.png)

Here I'm getting the result by query:

```
$subject_ids = implode(',', $_POST['subject_ids'])

SELECT * FROM table WHERE focusarea LIKE '%$subject_ids%' ;
```

The result is perfect, but there is nothing to display when I select more than one subject ids, like if selecting only one then it shows,
but when to select 1, 2, and 4, but there is nothing with this LIKE query...

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should normalize your data and get rid of the CSV, this is my advice.

Comment: In which form do you get `$_POST['subject_ids']` as string `1,2,3` or as a array `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: getting array as 1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` clause will not work in your case because using `LIKE '%1,2,3%'` in query will not get anything, as you as using Ids you should use `IN` instead of `LIKE`. `LIKE` will be used separately for each id if it is string.

As you are getting `$_POST['subject_ids']` as an array, query will be like

```
$subject_str = implode(',', $_POST['subject_ids']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE focusarea IN($subject_str)";
```

If your column `focusarea` is not integer then

```
$subject_str = "'".implode("','", $_POST['subject_ids'])."'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE focusarea IN($subject_str)";
```

Comment: perfect answer but I want to display result at least one id match from this array

Comment: @UmarShahzad : Apply condition if you have at least one search otherwise display all or default as you want.

Comment: please explain more ?

Comment: I want to show coach by filtering subjects check boxes if there is one match It should be display that coach if there is all match subjects then it also show how to do?

Comment: yes the query provided will do the same as you want

Comment: and subject ids that m adding in the table is like 1,2,5,6,9

Comment: your answer is working but it works only when all ids matching with coach's subject id....

Comment: check this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1a4b/7 or you can make your own and share what is not working ?

Comment: thanks @Rishi for your help its very knowledgeable for me but my problem solved with REGEXP ('1|3|5')..... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode` like,

**PHP**

```
$subject_id_aray = explode(",",$_POST['subject_ids']);
$in_array_string = array();
foreach($subject_id_aray as $values){
    $in_array_string[] = "'".$values."'";
}
```

**MySql**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE focusarea in (".implode(",",$in_array_string).") ;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have bug in `POST`.

Try to `echo`, `$subject_ids` befor inject to SQL.

You focus are is simple string of numbers, connected by `,`, but what you are sending by `POST` maybe is not correct.

Other problem, this don't look like you full code.
Provide you file, if this don't resolve problem.